# How to configure AWS SQS Queue to Listen already created S3 bucket's events

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs

I have aws S3 bucket which is created by aws console. Now I want to deploy AWS SQS Queue for listening that bucket's object creating events with the **Serverless** framework.

Can someone explain how to achieve the task?

Here are relevant parts of my **yml** file:

```
......

iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - sqs:*
      Resource:
        - "*"
......

resources:
  Resources:
    PDFConverterQueue:
      Type: "AWS::SQS::Queue"
      Properties:
        QueueName: "PDFConverterQueue"

     #### How can I configure this Queue to listen to previously created bucket's events.
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have better success to have the Lambda be invoked directly by the S3 event. The S3 requests are asynchronous and have exponential retry policies in place in case of failure.

```
functions:
  pdfConverter:
    handler: handler.pdfconverted
    events:
      - s3:
          bucket: pdftoconvert 
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
          existing: true
```

No need for an SQS queue so you save some resources.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But in my case, the converter is deployed on a server(EC2). It can't handle too many parallel processes. that's why I choose SQS to hold the events until others successfully processed by the converter.

Comment: @lahirudx Then I would recommend you add a Lambda between S3 and SQS. That way the Lambda receives the S3 requests, formats it for SQS and posts the details in there.

Comment: Isn't there a way to directly send events s3 to sqs. I already done it with via console. but I want deploy it with serverless.